# Viewing times and dates

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to view the time and date of each visit to a site in Google Analytics?

I've clicked in various places but could not find this information.

Comment: Not possible. You need to use something like http://piwik.org/

Comment: People voting to migrate:  Google Analytics questions should go to  webmasters rather than web apps (http://meta.superuser.com/questions/10755/please-migrate-google-analytics-questions-to-webmasters).  It doesn't appear that we can directly migrate.  @JohnSonderson: Probably need to delete here and repost there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Google Analytics questions go to [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible in Google Analytics itself. You can only view the total number of a stat e.g. visits for a day - a day being the shortest period of time Analytics will report on, or another specified date (day) range e.g. for a month.

You'd need another analytics service that specifically tracks and can report on this to get this information.

Comment: Please provide the names of a few alternative web services that do this so I can accept your answer.

Comment: Hi @JohnSonderson, I've done some looking around in my spare time, however I haven't found any services available that explicitly say that can do the tracking you're after (I do recall seeing them in years past however). If you can't find one yourself, you may have to consider writing it yourself.

Comment: One BIG BIG BIG consideration you need to keep in mind is user privacy. If you're tracking identifiable information, you need to make sure that you are either up front about it to visitors, or at least clearly state it in a Privacy Policy. Be aware of your country's privacy laws; e.g. here in Australia they are pretty strict.